# Passing a void value function as part of a function signature in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

First off I'm primarily a Java programmer, but I've been tasked with doing some network stuff in C. I've got a function with the following signature:

```
foo(int, void (*) (int, char *, int))
```

It's the `void (*)` that's throwing me for a loop. This is supposed to call another function (static)

```
bar(int, char *, int)
```

Now am I right in thinking that `foo` wants a pointer to `bar` with whatever variables I need at the time?
Calling

```
foo(1,myfunction(1,&anCharArray,10));
```

fails with a number of errors.

If anyone has any links to good articles on pointers that would also help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (esp. regarding your comment on Ouah's answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `void (*)(int, char *, int)` is an anonymous parameter of type 'pointer to function returning `void` and taking three arguments: an `int`, a `char *` and another `int`'.  You need to pass the name of such a function (in your case, `bar`) as the second argument to the function `foo`.  Personally, I'd prefer to see the declaration of `foo` written with a return type and names for parameters, and the declaration of `bar()` should also have a return type and names for the parameters.  The names do not have to match between function declaration and definition, but it is not usually regarded as good style to vary the names between them.

```
void foo(int num, void (*func)(int num, char *str, int len));
static void bar(int num, char *str, int len);
```

You can then call:

```
foo(10, bar);
```

Inside `foo()`, you will have code such as:

```
void foo(int num, void (*func)(int num, char *str, int len))
{
    char str[] = "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious";
    (*func)(num, str, strlen(str));
}
```

Or, if you're new school (not an archaic relic like me), then:

```
void foo(int num, void (*func)(int num, char *str, int len))
{
    char str[] = "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious";
    func(num, str, strlen(str));
}
```

These are equivalent.  I still prefer the explicit "I'm calling a function via a pointer to function" notation, but it isn't necessary and modern style tends to avoid it.

Comment: The declaration of foo is

int foo(portNum, void(*) dataHandler(portNum, char[] * data, int dataLength).

Thanks for the input. That really helps :)

Comment: The notation `char []*data` is not syntactically legal C; you might mean `char *data[]` (which means one thing) or `char *data` or `char data[]` (which mean something different).  And you should not pass a function that returns `int` as a pointer when the pointer expects a function that returns `void`.  The compiler should be warning you about this — type mismatches.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> foo(1,myfunction(1,&anCharArray,10))
> ```
>
> fails with a number of errors.

Try instead:

```
foo(1, myfunction)
```

The second parameter of  `foo` function is a function pointer but you were passing the return value of a function call.

Comment: How would I pass the values I need then?

Comment: @user832818 by adding parameters to `foo` function?